# Storage Spaces Utilization Doesn't Make Sense

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

Here's my setup:

Windows 10

- 1 2TB USB3 drive
- 1 3TB USB3 drive
- 3.59 TB Two way mirror storage space built from these drives

Previously I had 2x 2TB drives, but one failed, so the replacement is 3TB. I did the math on the utilization percentages of the individual drives and they're both equally loaded, but each at only half of the used amount of the pool. The storage space is using 1.59 TB of space, but each drive's individual utilization is only half of that.

Why is this? Shouldn't each drive be utilizing the full amount of the storage space's data? Shouldn't I be right at the limit of the first 2 TB drive and be in need of adding two more drives to expand storage capacity?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was actually only using the stated amount on each drive, meaning that the storage space reporting was indeed including the mirrored amount. All is well.